# Can I transfer my Forza 4 cars to my Gamertag instead of having to start all over?

Tags: xbox-network, forza-motorsport-4

I have been playing Forza4 under player 1 offline. I just got an Xbox live Gamertag and noticed none of my cars or achievements are there. How can I transfer player 1's cars and achievements to my Gamertag profile so I don't have to start from the beginning again?

Answer (score 2):

Xbox Live profiles store achievements in such a way that they cannot be transferred from Gamertag to Gamertag.

In Forza 4, the only way to transfer cars is to gift them. Both Gamertags must have Xbox Live gold, and you must have both on each other's friends list to do this.